# How to pass the params to two different tables in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

As a newbie I started to do API POC. I have a situation as explained below:

I have seekerController which has create method.I want that when a Post request makes then few parameters has to go seeker table and few needs to go profile table(This table also have the seekerID column). I want to do this with in Transaction commit. So after reading I started doing below:-

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
          seeker = Seeker.new(seeker_params)
          seeker.save!
          params[:seeker_id] = seeker[:id]

          seekerprofile = SeekerProfile.new(seekerprofile_params)
          seekerprofile.save!
          end
      render json: {status: 'success', message: 'Request is processed successully', data:seeker},status: :created;
```

I have below definition:(I have doubt i the below way is correct)

```
def seeker_params
    params.require(:seeker).permit(:username, :alias, :mobile_number, :country_code, :email_address, :description, :status)
  end
  def seekerprofile_params
    params.require(:seeker_profile).permit(:seeker_id, :first_name, :middle_name, :last_name, :date_of_birth, :pincode, :building_name, :address, :email_address, :description, :status)

  end
```

Let me put my question straight forward here:-
I have post body request parameter like below:

```
{
      "username" : "TestName12",
      "alias" :  "TestAlia12",
     #above should go to seeker table
      "first_name":"xyz",
      "Last_Name":"abc"
      #above should go above Seekerprofile table. seekerprofile has seekerid also.
}
```

My Model is below:-

```
> class SeekerProfile < ApplicationRecord
> 
>   belongs_to :seeker end
```

I have tried what i have posted in start code , but i am getting the error  as seekerprofile_params is empty. So I am sure my approach is wrong.

Can anyone please provide the sample code , how to do that? I am java guy , so fresher for ruby.

Comment: What do you mean "it's not working"? That's not a real problem description. You'll have to be more specific.

Comment: @samash Does the `Seeker`model have a `has_one` or `has_many`relation with `SeekerProfile`?

Comment: @anuj, Seeker have  has_many relation with seekerprofile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the limited information that is given, it seems as though the problem could be related to the `seeker_id` field being blank in the result of `seekerprofile_params`. Basically, we're setting `params[:seeker_id]` as `params[:seeker_id] = seeker[:id]` after saving `Seeker`. But while creating params for creating `SeekerProfile`, we use `seekerprofile_params` which looks for `seeker_id` in `params[:seeker_profile][:seeker_id]` since we use `params.require(:seeker_profile)` before permitting `seeker_id`. Since `SeekerProfile` does not get a `seeker_id`, it may not get saved depending on how the model is setup. 
However, in case you're trying to create both, a `Seeker` as well as a `SeekerProfile`, you may want to check out [nested attributes in Rails](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

Edit after receiving more inputs:
Considering that the API contract cannot change and needs to be maintained, the following approach could be used to create a `seeker` and a `seeker_profile`: 
1) We could change the model `Seeker` to accept nested attributes for `SeekerProfile` as follows:

```
# app/models/seeker.rb

has_many :seeker_profiles  # As mentioned in the question comments
accepts_nested_attributes_for :seeker_profiles
```

2) The controller code could then be changed as follows:

```
# app/controllers/seeker_controller.rb

def create
  seeker = Seeker.new(creation_params)
  seeker.save!

  render json: {status: 'success', message: 'Request is processed successully', data:seeker},status: :created
end

private

def creation_params
  params.permit(:username, :alias).merge(seeker_profiles_attributes: [seeker_profile_creation_params])
end

def seeker_profile_creation_params
  params.permit(:first_name, :last_name)
end
```

What happens here is basically we allow the `seeker` model to accept attributes for `seeker_profiles` during creation. These attributes are accepted by the model using the `seeker_profiles_attributes` attribute writer. Since the relationship is a `has_many` relationship, `seeker_profiles_attributes` accepts an array of objects, where each hash object represents one `seeker_profile` child to be created.
In the code mentioned above, I've assumed that only one `seeker_profile` is to be created. In case your API changes and wants to accept multiple profiles during creation, I would leave that upto you to figure out, with the assurance that you could get back in the comments in case you're stuck. 
Another thing to note is that the `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` block is not required since failure in any of the objects being created would rollback the entire transaction anyway.

Comment: Thanks Anuj. after keeping byebug, i released that, i am not able to prepare parameter to pass seekerprofile table.I edited the question

Comment: I've updated the answer taking the new inputs into account. This may help with creation.

Comment: I am wondering, how in one go SeekerProfile table will have seeker_id as reference. seeker_id is the id of seeker table and foreign key for seekerprofile table.

Comment: That's what Rails does under the hood when we use nested attributes. It creates the records, as well as handles the foreign key constraint automatically. The code for the same can be found here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b9ca94caea2ca6a6cc09abaffaad67b447134079/activerecord/lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb#L333

Comment: Thanks Anuj !! I have not yet tried. I started reading about nested attributes.I need to have complete understanding how it works..will let you know

Comment: The approach worked Anuj..Thanks. Can you please recommend any good tutorial for me..

Comment: I'd gone through the Rails guides tutorial: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html
However, I think making your own project after the tutorial would be the best thing to do (Which you're already doing I believe).
Also, do go through at least the sections listed under "Models" on this page: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/
Lastly, it's absolutely alright to get lost in the "magic" that goes on under the hood in Rails. Initially, it would be best to follow conventions without giving much thought to how you can customize. Soon everything will make sense! All the best!